# Handling of more than one relationship type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Say I have this model:

```
public class Company
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee CEO { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CorporateContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And code:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUp(TestContext _)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CorporateContext>());
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanHandleMultipleRelations()
{
    Company Disney = new Company { Name = "Disney" };

    Employee Mickey = new Employee { Name = "Mickey Mouse" };
    Employee Donald = new Employee { Name = "Donald Duck" };
    Employee Goofy = new Employee { Name = "Goofy Goof" };

    Disney.CEO = Mickey;

    Disney.Employees.Add(Mickey);
    Disney.Employees.Add(Donald);
    Disney.Employees.Add(Goofy);

    using (CorporateContext context = new CorporateContext())
    {
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    using (CorporateContext context = new CorporateContext())
    {
        context.Companies.Add(Disney);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There is no issue with the model as EF is able to create the correct database schema.

The issue is when an entity is in both relationships, e.g. Mickey is both the CEO and an employee.

When calling `SaveChanges` I get this exception:

```
Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.
The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception.
Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
See the InnerException for details.
```

And inner exception:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
```

I think I understand the issue:

- the `CEO` property is translated as a **FK** in the `Company` table so when I insert a new company EF needs the `Id` of some employee
- the `Employee` class is mapped to a table with a FK pointing to the `Company` table to honor the 1-n relationship, so when I insert an employee I should specify a company

So when I insert a company whose CEO is a new employee EF is lost because there is a catch 22: to insert the company it needs the CEO id, so it needs to insert the CEO, but for that it needs the id of the company...

I've tried to help EF by explicitly defining the FK:

```
[ForeignKey("Company_Id")]
public Company Company { get; set; }
public long? Company_Id { get; set; }
```

But even if all is nullable, and EF understands this as all the columns are indeed nullable, EF still does not want to save it.

I imagine I could do a two steps insert: first the employee, then the company.

But then I guess I'd lose the transactionality and I'd like to keep things simple if possible.

So what are the best workarounds/fixes for solving this issue?

Comment: Typical situation for two SaveChanges() calls wrapped in a TransactionScope.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks, so there is no "automated" of doing it?